# Problems connecting to WhatsApp from desktop

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, connection-issues

I always have problems connecting to WhatsApp desktop/web (I usually use desktop, but it's the same concept) - it says it can't reach the phone.

Now, the thing is that it has problems connecting even when WhatsApp is open on my phone and I'm using it (not in the background, actually open).
The internet is working well both on the phone and computer, since I use it at the moment - but it still can't connect or will take significant time and multiple tries until succeeded.

Ideas? Something I can check?

---

*Device details: LG G5, Android 7.0, stock, no root*

Comment: try this: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/web/28080002/?category=5245260
it might be a bug or something. You may try to use another web browers and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really the case since I'm eventually able to connect but it takes forever and loses the connection all the time (and I'm using the desktop app usually, not web) 